# Reducing Executable Size - Comment out calls/usage vs Remove files/folders

Tags: c++, c++11, dll, linker

My goal is to reduce the binary size of an existing `Visual Studio 2013` C++ project.

As I understood from my previous semi-related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721820/is-c-linkage-smart-enough-to-avoid-linkage-of-unused-libs), the `Linker` will include pieces of code, in the binary file, **only** if the code is used.

As part of my attempts to identify which components (classes/folders/filters) in my projects are the largest, I tried the following:

1. Comment out calls/usage of these components.
2. 1 + completely remove these components (files/folder) from my project.

I expected `2` to give the same results as `1` in terms of binary size.
However found out that using `2` as much more impact on the size, meaning size reduction is much better.

#### Questions

1. Is my assumption valid (`2` to give the same results as `1`)?
2. If so, why don't I get the expected results?

#### Update 1

It seems like the `Linker` still includes code of unused functions, as if its logic tells it that it cannot exclude these functions since they might be used somehow (for example: exported functions)
Just a reminder, the functions/classes I wish to exclude are not exported.

**Example 1**

```
void func(HINSTANCE, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
   // do nothing
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
   // do nothing
}
```

generates DLL of size ~300KB

**Example 2**

```
void func(HINSTANCE, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
   // do something huge
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
   // do nothing
}
```

generated DLL of size ~400KB

#### Question:

When generating DLL, if function is not used/called and it is not exported, why would the linker include its code?

I configured my `Linker` flags based on [Do unused functions get optimized out?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6215782/1798187)

Comment: It would be easier, if you gave an example.

Comment: @Yakk Compiling in Release and Optimization flags favor size over speed. This is more a question on which code the linker includes in DLL and why then  a question of how to resolve my issue.

Comment: I mean every flag passed to your compiler.

Comment: I'm sure providing the **all** information is more useful, but for the sake of the question, should I be concern with specific flags?

Comment: By the size of the binary, do you mean the size of the `.exe` file, or the size of the process image in memory?

Comment: I mean the size of the `.dll` file

Comment: If `func` is not used, I think it should be static or placed in anonymous namespace. When it is not, compiler can assume that the function can be required by another source file.

Comment: As a last resort you can compress `.dll` file using a program such as `UPX`.