# Visual Studio static library linking. Will unused functions or classes get optimized away?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, static-libraries, static-linking

Is there such an option for visual studio to optimize away code which isn't used at any point within code?

For example if I have function `int foo(bar b)` in my static library, but the executable I link it into does not use that function. Will that function be optimized away by the compiler / linker? If not then is there a way to make this kind of optimization using compiler / linker option in visual studio?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215782/do-unused-functions-get-optimized-out

Comment: @BenjyKessler Yeah but my question is about static libraries.

Comment: If an .obj file is a part of a static library, and nothing in that .obj file is used, the entire file is left out. Beyond that you need to experiment with your linker and see for yourself.