# Does the linker refer to the main code

Tags: c, linker

Let assume I am having three source files main.c, a.c and b.c. In the main.c are called some of the functions (not all) that are defined in a.c. None of the functions defined in b.c are called (used) by main.c. In main.c is the main function. Then we have a makefile that compiles all the source files(main.c, a.c and b.c) and then links them to produce executable file, in my case intel hex file. My question is: Does the linker know in which file the main function resides and knowing that to determine what part of the object files to link together? I mean if the linker produces the exe file based only on the recipe of the rule to make the target then no matter how many functions are called in our application code the size of the executable will be the same because the recipe says to link all the object files. For example we compile the three source files and we get three object files: main.o a.o and b.o (the bigger the object files are, the bigger the exe file is). I know you would say if you dont want anything from the b.c then do not include it in the build. But it means that every time I want to change the application (include/exclide modules) I need to change the makefile too. And another thing is how the linker knows what part of the object file to take, does it understand the C language? I hope you understand my question, excuse my bad English.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do unused functions get optimized out?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215782/do-unused-functions-get-optimized-out)

Comment: Generally agree with LaurentHermand's answer, but what I suggest: compile `a.c` and `b.c` as static libraries. Then the linker is more likely to only pull functions that are actually needed.

Answer (score 2):

1) *Does the linker know in which file the main function resides and knowing that to determine what part of the object files to link together?*
Maybe there are options of your toolchain (compiler/linker) to enable this kind of optimizations, I mean removing unused functions from link, but I have big doubt for global functions (could be possible for *static* functions).

2) *And another thing is how the linker knows what part of the object file to take, does it understand the C language?*
Linker may detect if a function or variable is not used by the application (once again, check the available options), but it is not really the objective of this tool. However if you compile/link some functions as library functions (see options), you can generate a "library" file and then link this library with other object files. The functions of the library will then be included by the linker ONLY if they are used.

**What I suggest**: use compilation flags (#ifdef...) to include or exclude parts of code from compilation/link.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only those functions in the executable that are eventually called from `main`, use a library of object files.

Basically the smallest unit the linker will extract from a library is the object file. Whatever symbols are in that object file will also be resolved, until all symbols are resolved.

In other words, if **none** of the symbols in an object file are needed, it won't end up in the result. If **at least one symbol** is needed, it will get linked in its entirety.

No, the linker does not understand C. Note that a lot of language compilers create object files (C++, FORTRAN, ..., and assemblers). A linker resolves **symbols**, which are names attached to values.

John Levine has written a book, "[Linkers and Loaders](http://www.iecc.com/linker/)", available on the 'net, which will give you an in-depth understanding of linkers, symbols, and object files.