# Does an unused function gets compiled?

Tags: c++, c, linker

I was wondering if I include a library file which contains say 5 functions and I only use 1 of them, will the rest of the functions compile too?

Comment: Depends of the compiler/linker.  What tools are you using?

Comment: It depends on the compiler. This question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215782/do-unused-functions-get-optimized-out).

Comment: If you use a library, the functions are already compiled. I think there's some terminology confusion here.

Comment: @molbdnilo he probably wants to know if the unused functions will be in the final executable or not.

Comment: It will compile whole code, assume of a scenario, you have 5 function, you are using only 4, and try giving a wrong syntax in the 5th one, you will get compilation error right? Hence it will compile all, it may not execute it.

Comment: @Jabberwocky exactly