# Does unnecessary C++ code end up in my completed program?

Tags: c++, g++, c-preprocessor, header-files

Let's say I'm including a header file that has tons of functions.

```
#include "1000Functions.h"

Function1(42);
Function2("Hello");
Function1000("geeks!");
```

But, I just want to use a few of the functions from the header. After preprocessing, compiling, and linking (for example, with g++), would my program include all 1000 functions, or just the 3 that I used?

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215782/do-unused-functions-get-optimized-out#:~:text=No%3A%20for%20unused%20globally%20available,if%20there%20exist%20internal%20references.

Comment: *Let's say I'm including a header file that has tons of functions.* -- What is in the `h` files are probably not function bodies, only function prototypes.

Comment: in general, you "pay for what you use".  Only the object code for the functions you use should end up in your final executable code.

Comment: Depends on the compiler and the compiler optimization level.  Some compilers may be lazy at the lowest optimization level and throw everything in (this is the faster build).  At higher optimization levels, the compiler would eliminate any unused functions (and the linker would help too).  You can verify this by having the compiler generate a "map" file or a cross-reference of all the functions.

Comment: Please read a good [C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) then the documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and of [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). See also [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this article](https://tetzank.github.io/posts/removing-unused-code/) that was useful. Using `objdump -tC ProgramName` can show you the unnecessary code that ends up being loaded into .text when your program is loaded into the memory.

Link-time optimization was what I was looking for, which worked for me once I added both of these tags to the linking command, not just `-flto`.

```
-O2 -flto
```